# How to synchronise bookmarks between Google Chrome and Opera?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, opera, opera-10

I use both [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) as well as [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29). Is there any way by which I can "auto synchronise" the bookmarks between Chrome and Opera?

By "auto synchronise", I mean whenever I bookmark a page in Chrome, it should also be bookmarked in Opera's bookmark list and vice versa.

Comment: For those like me looking at this question over a decade later, I've been happy with [Speed Dial 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/speed-dial-2-new-tab/jpfpebmajhhopeonhlcgidhclcccjcik) as a cloud-backed bookmarks system that feels almost like Opera's native Speed Dial. While cloud bookmark systems aren't seamlessly integrated into the browser and don't support bookmarklets, until browsers start playing nice with each other they are probably our best bet.

Answer (score 5):

**[Transmute](http://www.gettransmute.com/)** will convert, **synchronize**, sort, organize and remove duplicates from your bookmarks and more.

Transmute supports all of the major web browsers including **Google Chrome**, Mozilla Firefox, Internet Explorer, **Opera**, Apple Safari, Chromium, Flock and Konqueror!

[image]

*Transmute is freeware and portable, no installation required.*

note: automated/scheduled cross-browser conversion is only available in the Pro version ($20).

Comment: Not sure before but, as of August 2011, the [free version](http://www.gettransmute.com/download/) does not appear to offer a single useful feature. Most browsers can import and export bookmarks natively.

Comment: New Opera Bookmarks not supported by Transmute ... :-(

Answer (score 3):

[Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) is what you're after. There is also [BookmarkSync](http://www.bookmarksync.com/download/default.php) which sits in your system tray.

Comment: Any other solution?

Comment: added another possibility.

Comment: Oh John! It also doesn't support chrome.Give me more.

Comment: Have you considered a bookmarking service like Delicious? http://delicious.com/

Comment: I'll go through it n let u know my response.

Comment: Xmarks does not suppport Opera and BookmarkSync does not work as advertised. We our of luck :(

Answer (score 2):

http://www.xmarks.com/ -- web site says it works on Opera, I've used it on Firefox and Chrome, works very well.

Comment: Nothing interesting.
Xmarks for chrome is still in alpha version.
For Opera,no version yet released.

Comment: Any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

One more way to use Google Bookmarks in both Opera and Chrome (and probably any other browser):

1. Add a bookmark to Google Bookmarks
   1.1 Chrome and Opera both have extensions to add pages to Google Bookmarks
   1.2 Or use the 'Google Bookmark' bookmarklet found at the bottom of the [Google Bookmarks list](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/)
2. Add a custom search engine to search for your bookmarks using the address bar. For example `gb bookmarks` will search for bookmarks tagged or named 'bookmark', where `gb` is the keyword for the Google Bookmarks search engine.

The idea and instructions on how to create a Google Bookmarks search engine come from here: https://metaed.blogspot.com/2008/12/using-google-bookmarks-in-google-chrome.html

The article describes how to create this search engine for Chrome, but the same instructions work for Opera.

Answer (score -1):

A superior solution, in my humble opinion is having the bookmarks in the cloud. I use Google bookmarks and access it from any web browser or computer and every thing is always synchronized. 
As for Opera, here's how to use Google Bookmarks almost seamlessly with Opera:
http://my.opera.com/abadr/blog/2009/10/31/use-google-bookmarks-with-opera-browser#comments.

Comment: Could you please explain how to use Google Bookmarks with opera? Generally at Super User its good etiquette to post content, not links to others content