# How can I import Opera bookmarks into Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, opera

> Not the same thing: [How to synchronise bookmarks between Google Chrome and Opera?](https://superuser.com/questions/69011/how-to-synchronise-bookmarks-between-google-chrome-and-opera)

While I know that I can use a service like Xmarks to synchronize them between the two browsers, and while I know that a method exists to export the bookmarks as HTML, then reimport them, are there any other methods?

Will Chrome look on install to see if there are any Opera bookmarks?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Export bookmarks from Opera as a HTML file (menu *File/Import and Export/Export Opera bookmarks*).

To import into Chrome, open a new tab and type `chrome:bookmarks`. This will display a page that is not accessible from the customize 'spanner' menus.

You will see an organise tab with a drop down menu. The last options are import to and export from HTML file.

There is no need to use third-party software to 'translate' bookmarks any more.

Comment: Nice, a bit out of date on my original problem, but this seems to be what people need to know going forward. Thanks!

Comment: "Not accessible"?  It's exactly the same page I get with Wrench > Bookmark Manager (Ctrl-Shift-O).  I'm on Chrome 19, but remember it being similar in earlier versions.

Comment: Chrome import of Opera-29-exported bookmarks.html does not appear to import bookmarks in folders/subdirectories. Any way to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

I found bug trying export Opera bookmarklets into Chrome : Opera bookmarklet should not be contain  empty folders and folders without name (otherwise while Chrome stops importing process after empty folder / folder without name position)

So 3 steps migrating Opera bookmarks to Chrome:

1. Check and delete Opera bookmarks for empty folders / folders without name (this applies Trash folder too - so clean it up)
2. Go to Opera menu button - Settings - Import and export - Export bookmarks as HTML (choose file name and location)
3. Open Chome's Bookmark Manager (Ctrl+Shift+O), find Organize menu - Import bookmarks from HTML file... (and locate Opera's exported file)

Answer (score 2):

Opera 35.0 appears to have no Import/Export option under settings, and they have deactivated Opera Link, so there is no way to do this except through other 3rd party software. Transmute does not appear to work.

Comment: Same thing on Opera 41.0

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, Chrome installer has no Opera bookmarks import feature (supports only I.E. and probably Firefox). Try to use Transmute -- this tool supports all major browsers (without intermediate exporting the bookmarks to HTML from the browser) and some other formats. In addition, it features some other handy stuff which you may also be interested in.

Comment: The trick is to get them out of Opera in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution would be web based bookmarks.  The advantage to web based book marks is that they are always available, from any browser, on any platform, and never need to be imported/exported.  Foxmarks does have web based bookmarks, as do other web services.

Comment: The trick is to get them out of Opera in the first place.