# Opera Bookmarks to Chrome Malfunction

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, opera, export, import

I am attempting to move my Opera bookmarks to Chrome. I created an HTML file for the bookmarks while I was in Opera. I looked at the new file, and saw that the bookmarks are there, but they are not ordered in the way they were in the browser.

I keep so many bookmarks that I put them into folders once I have a few. The HTML file seemed to have them listed in the order in which I collected them. It did indicate various folders by having bolded text, but these were not in the order I keep them either. They were also in the order in which they were created.

I decided it didn't matter. They were all there, after all, so I planned to just import them to Chrome and organize them once they were home.

I followed the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/314006/how-can-i-import-opera-bookmarks-into-chrome/570970#570970) to import the HTML file into Chrome.

Only three of the bookmarks were imported. The first three bookmarks were imported, none of the folders and none of the later bookmarks. The three bookmarks that were imported were the ones that Opera did not put into a folder because they were the first three I ever created.