# Import settings and password and bookmarks from opera to chrome

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, opera, import

A while ago I migrated from Chrome to Opera and I imported all of my bookmarks and settings into Opera, thanks to its powerful import tool.
As a strategy for the probable future retro-migration, is there any way to import all of opera settings and other stuff back into Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Go to chrome settings, have you tried pressing the button "Import bookmarks and settings..."?

[image: Import bookmarks and settings...]

It should come up with a menu like this, is Opera not listed in the drop-down menu?
[image: Menu]

Comment: Exactly! Opera is NOT listed here. I ended up like [this](http://i.imgur.com/gX9bEDk.jpg)

Comment: Sorry, I have marked this question as a duplicate. The answer can be found here: http://superuser.com/questions/314006/how-can-i-import-opera-bookmarks-into-chrome

Comment: Thanks @Bungicasse, but I not only want to import Opera bookmarks, but also OTHER stuff, like passwords, cookies, browsing history etc. I have some ideas how to do this for bookmarks. Here I demand a solution for OTHER things.