# Share bookmarks between Firefox and Opera

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, opera

Is there any tool or service to share or sync bookmarks between Firefox and Opera? I'm currently using both browsers in the same computer and it'd be nice to have the same set of bookmarks available.

I know I can export and import them manually but that's designed for permanent migrations. I'm also aware of [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) but it does not support Opera (there's a [workaround](https://addons.opera.com/addons/extensions/details/xmarks-mini/1.0/?display=en) but it doesn't feel practical).

Comment: Relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/69011/how-to-synchronise-bookmarks-between-google-chrome-and-opera

Answer (score 1):

I use [Delicious](http://www.delicious.com) to store my bookmarks online. I can access them from any browser and from every computer.

Comment: Is there a tool to keep Delicious in sync with either browser's bookmarks? I wouldn't like to have a *third* copy of my bookmarks... :)

Comment: I know you can manually export/import them from delicious into your browser. There may be a firefox addon for it. Try searching.

Comment: Watch out with delicious! I've been using delicious since 2006 and they deleted my account one day for no reason.