# How do I convert Opera's bookmarks into Firefox' and preserve the bookmark nicknames / keywords?

Tags: firefox, browser, bookmarks, opera

Both Opera and Firefox have a function that allows you to type a nickname / keyword into the address bar, and then automatically load the bookmark URL associated with that nickname/keyword. More info: [Opera bookmark nicknames](https://web.archive.org/web/20150516202809/http://help.opera.com/Windows/12.10/en/bookmarks.html) | [Firefox bookmark keywords](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Using_keyword_searches#Creating_bookmarks_with_keywords)

Opera 12 is currently my main browser, but I am now thinking of using Firefox as my main browser after the [Opera 15 fiasco](http://www.infoworld.com/t/web-browsers/blink-based-opera-15-strikes-sour-note-users-222025). I used Transmute as recommended by the current top answer in this SU post to export my Opera bookmarks into Firefox: [How to synchronise bookmarks between Google Chrome and Opera?](https://superuser.com/q/69011/10259) - but it doesn't preserve the nicknames/keywords of my Opera bookmarks. They are gone upon conversion to Firefox bookmarks.

**Is there another software (offline or web application), browser extension or solution that I can use to convert or transfer my Opera bookmarks into Firefox *while preserving* bookmark nicknames/keywords?**

I am using Opera 12 and Firefox on Windows 7.

Comment: Doesn't the normal method work? In Opera: Bookmarks -> Manage bookmarks -> File -> Export as HTML... and in Firefox: Bookmarks -> Import and Backup -> Import bookmarks from HTML?

Comment: @Wk_of_Angmar D'oh! That seems to work. Put your comment as an answer, so I could accept it.

Comment: @galacticninja Since Wk_of_Angmar doesn't use the site anymore, feel free to copy and post it as the answer yourself.