# How do I sync Google Chrome for Android with the desktop Opera browser?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, android, opera

I use Opera on my Windows PC but I think the Android version of Opera feels clunky so I use Chrome on Android. Is there a way to sync my data like bookmarks, open tabs, etc, across these two browsers bi-directionally?

Answer (score 0):

No. As of today browsers use their own solutions for synchronization and there seems to be no intention to be compatible with each other. For the desktop [there are solutions to sync the data between different browsers](https://superuser.com/questions/69011/how-to-synchronise-bookmarks-between-google-chrome-and-opera), but this is not the case in a smartphone/desktop scenario.

In the worst case scenario you can sync your Chrome on Android with a Chrome on the desktop and then sync that desktop Chrome with your desktop Opera, else you'd have to choose between sticking to a single browser on all platforms or giving up synchronization between them.

Comment: I'm willing to go through the trouble of setting up the desktop version of chrome to work as a proxy to opera, but how would I automate that process?

Comment: The sync between desktop Chrome and Android Chrome is automatic. The sync between the desktop Chrome and desktop Opera could use e.g. Transmute, the solution in the linked question. (Also note that it's not free, free solutions like Xmarks usually only sync one aspect of your browsing, like bookmarks.)